# Can I convert a gradle report after creating it as xml to html

Tags: gradle, report

Example:
I create a Findbugs report of type xml. 
I put this xml somwhere and now I want to convert it to HTML without running Findbugs again but using the report converter.

Same for Unit Test etc

Any idea?

Comment: use groovy and xslt? example: http://www.pleus.net/blog/?p=1448

Comment: Ye thats possible but can I reuse the existing xsl Files from gradle. Are they available somwhere?